# How would I determine if this infinite series is convergent or divergent using the limit comparison test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2^n \over3+4^n}$$

My thinking is that $4^n$ will grow much more rapidly than $2^n$, and the +3 in the denominator is negligable. Therfore, I should compare it to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$1 \over n$. But I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: note that $$\frac{2^n}{3+4^n}\lt\frac{2^n}{4^n}=(\frac{1}{2})^n$$

Comment: By "solve this infinite series" you mean "determine whether this series converges or not".

Comment: It seems it would be more comparable to $(\frac{1}{2})^n$